# RPy2 and Bioconductor: gene expression example

Tags: rpy2, bioconductor

I'm trying to work out how to do the classic gene expression [example](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15461798) in Bioconductor using Rpy2, and I'm stuck right at the beginning.  How do you load the data?  In R we do:

```
> library('ALL')
> library('limma')
> data('ALL')
```

In Python we do:

```
>>> import rpy2.robjects as robjects
>>> from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
>>> base = importr('base')
>>> ALL = importr('ALL')
```

How to do the Python equivalent of:

```
> data('ALL') ??
```

I don't see an example where package data is loaded in the docs for the extensions.  I thought this could be it but it seems that data is not of the right class because it has `signature "character"` when fed to `featureNames`:

```
>>> data = robjects.r('data(ALL)')
>>> data.rclass
<rpy2.rinterface.SexpVector - Python:0x1004b3828 / R:0x10376d558>
>>> featureNames = robjects.r('featureNames')
>>> featureNames(data)
Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function "featureNames", for signature "character"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rpy2-2.2.2dev_20110818-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 82, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rpy2-2.2.2dev_20110818-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 34, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function "featureNames", for signature "character"
```

UPDATE:  I think I have it now:

```
>>> import rpy2.robjects as robjects
>>> from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
>>> base =  importr('base')
>>> ALL = importr('ALL')
>>> data = robjects.r('data(ALL)')
>>> data.rclass
<rpy2.rinterface.SexpVector - Python:0x258b190 / R:0xdf86c8>
>>> data = robjects.globalenv['ALL']
>>> data
<RS4 - Python:0x2591490 / R:0x29a2134>
>>> data.rclass
<rpy2.rinterface.SexpVector - Python:0x258b3b0 / R:0xdf85c8>
>>> featureNames = robjects.r('featureNames')
>>> featureNames(data)
<StrVector - Python:0x23e4f08 / R:0x304fc00>
['1000..., '1001..., '1002..., ..., 'AFFX..., 'AFFX..., 'AFFX...]
>>> exprs = robjects.r['exprs']
>>> e = exprs(data)
>>> e
<Matrix - Python:0x23b2da0 / R:0x84d8000>
[7.597323, 5.046194, 3.900466, ..., 3.095670, 3.342961, 3.842535]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem should be solved in a Python package containing [bioconductor extensions to rpy2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpy2-bioconductor-extensions)

Comment: Thanks.  I am working my way through the docs.  I didn't see this "shortcut" of executing R code right away.

Comment: The extensions contain Python classes to represent the R S4 classes. For loading the ALL data set, that's buried in the main documentation for rpy2. Try 'ALL = importr("ALL"); ALL.ALL'